# Multi-Tenant OIDC (Okta): How to know the domain/site when exchanging authorization code for a token

Tags: openid-connect, okta

I have successfully added SSO support via Okta to my multi-tenant (Phoenix) SaaS web app. However, I feel that I'm missing something important, and I'm coming here for clarity.

In Okta, in order to access my web app via SSO, each of my customers needs to create an "application" that represents my app. This generates a `client_id` and a `client_secret`. In addition, the customer has a unique Okta domain, e.g. `foo.okta.com`. For each of my customers, I store these three values in the database.

Now, when using IdP-initiated authentication and the "Authorization Flow," a user at customer Foo clicks on the tile in their SSO dashboard for my app. Okta then makes a request to a configurable URL on my site, e.g. http://example.com/auth/okta. When it does so, it very handily (and, I think, per spec) tacks on the issuer as a query string, e.g., http://example.com/auth/okta?iss=https://foo.okta.com&provider=okta

Perfect! Now I can use the `iss` param to lookup the client ID, and redirect properly to the Okta authorization URL.

However, and this is where my question lies, when Okta makes a callback to my site with an authorization code, I then need to call Okta directly to exchange that code for an ID and access token. But Okta does not provide the domain (iss parameter) in the callback, and I have no way of looking up the client secret to authorize my call to the `/token` endpoint!

To resolve this, I am creating a cookie containing the client domain during the initiation step and reading it back during the success callback, but that just seems wrong. Especially so since I have read *everything* I can find on this issue, but nothing seems to address it. All of which makes me think I've overlooked something painfully obvious.

Any insight would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Are you working on a web app with the backend or a SPA?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. Saving it in the session on the server would be another way. Also I would recommend to add a CSRF protection using a state parameter.
You can use [`state`](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#request-parameters) query parameter of [authorization endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) to pass an encrypted information from your app to the Identity Provider. Also save `state` in the session. Your app will get it back unchanged as a `state` query parameter in the [callback](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthResponse) along side with the `access_code` in `code` query parameter. By comparing the saved `state` with the received one, you protect your app from CSRF attacks.

```
  GET /authorize?
    response_type=code
    &scope=openid%20profile%20email
    &client_id=s6BhdRkqt3
    &state=af0ifjsldkj
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb HTTP/1.1
  Host: server.example.com
```

```
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Location: https://client.example.org/cb?
    code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
    &state=af0ifjsldkj
```

For SPAs use PKCE flow.

[Single Sign On docs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/oin-sso-overview/) from Okta that also described multi-tenancy.

[Example](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/attack-protection/state-parameters#redirect-users) of CSRF protection.